# serverless-offline-sqs ListQueues not displaying queue

Tags: serverless-framework, elastic-mq

In my sls project, I setup sqs offline usage as shown below using [this article](https://aws.plainenglish.io/how-to-test-amazon-sqs-with-docker-using-serverless-b717258f5d3d).

1. npm installed serverless-offline-sqs as dev dependency
2. Included serverless-offline-sqs after serverless-offline in serverless.ts plugins section
3. Added custom configuration for the Queue,

```
"serverless-offline-sqs": {
      autoCreate: true,
      apiVersion: "2012-11-05",
      endpoint: "http://localhost:9324",
      region: "us-east-1",
      accessKeyId: "root",
      secretAccessKey: "root",
      skipCacheInvalidation: false,
    },
```

4. Included Queue resource in serverless.ts resources section:

```
FooQueue: {
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue",
      Properties: {
        QueueName: "foo.fifo",
        FifoQueue: true,
        VisibilityTimeout: 60,
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 345600,
      },
    },
```

5. Running ElasticMQ docker

```
docker run -p 9324:9324 -p 9325:9325 softwaremill/elasticmq-native
```

6. Started serverless offline **sls offline start**

Attempting to list Queues, does not display fifo.queue. Wondering why autoCreate is not creating the queue. List Queue action curl response:

```
curl "http://localhost:9324?Action=ListQueues"
<ListQueuesResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
                <ListQueuesResult>
                  
                </ListQueuesResult>
                <ResponseMetadata>
                  <RequestId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RequestId>
                </ResponseMetadata>
              </ListQueuesResponse>%
```

Wondering what am I missing to auto create the queue for offline mode? Offline start shows "offline: Starting Offline SQS: dev/us-east-1." message.

Versions:

```
"serverless-offline-sqs": "^6.0.0",
"serverless-offline": "^8.1.0",
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. Nothing wrong with plugin.  Though I added lambda function handler for SQS events, I forgot to include the function in serverless.ts under "functions" resource.  Including it in functions autoCreated the queue as expected.